# Spinograms vs. conditional densityplots

Tags: r, conditional-probability, density-function, nonlinearity

I have a binary response variable (hail) and multiple continuous predictor variables. My aim is to understand the linear/non-linear relationship of the predictors to the response to be able to **justify the use of a linear or non-linear model**.

I got the advice to use conditional density plots (`cdplot()` in R). Since I experienced some problems due to the distribution of my data ([SO question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/742TE.png)), I also tried spinograms (`spineplot()`). To visualize point densities of my x-variable, I used `lattice::densityplot()` since "conditional densities are more reliable for high-density regions of x".

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

*Personal interpretation:*
I read about the interpretation of `cdplot()`[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49562/interpretation-of-conditional-density-plots). 'Spinograms' and 'Cond. Dens. plot' show the probability of hail/NoHail for a given temperature. `Spinograms` provide a grouped x-axis view based on a `hist()`call on the x-axis variable. 'Cond. Dens. plot' shows basically the same as Spinograms, just smoothed?

1. I´m afraid of the high probabilities of `spineplot()` and `cdplot()` in the regions of -18 to -10 since only a few points of my x-variable fall into this range and therefore this region is "less reliable".
2. How to interpret the differences of `spineplot()` and `cdplot()` in the region of -18°C? `spineplot()` shows a probability of around 0.1 while `cdplot()` shows a peak with roughly 0.3?

I would conclude that `spineplot()`shows a non-linear relationship while `cdplot()` shows this as well, however with a slight tendency to a negative linear relationship?